# Small and fast (and preferably capless) flash drive (> ~80 MB/s write)

Tags: flash-drive

I have a [P-FD128TBOP-GE](https://www.pny.com/turbo-3-0-usb-flash-drive?sku=P-FD128TBOP-GE) and it's generally good, except:

- It's shown signs of corruption on a few occasions (but that seems to have stopped...)
- It's too big/a little uncomfortable in my pocket!

However, it's 128 GiB, achieves a ~100 MB/s sequential write speed *in practice* (not just benchmarks!), and is capless (good, because that means I don't have to worry about losing the cap).

Is there any flash drive that satisfies these conditions while also being noticeably smaller, ideally like one of those "nano"-sized ones? **Note:** I want something that won't easily break off a keychain.
I'm specifically looking for fast write speeds; for me that's at least ~80 MB/s. If it has other good properties I might be a bit flexible here and go down to like 60 MB/s, it depends, but generally I want at least 80 MB/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corsair CMFSL3X2-128GB 128GB Voyager is one I use myself, it's an extremely compact design, 128gb and has 90mb/s write speed, which seems to fit your specifications, however, I'm not sure about how strong the key ring attachment is, I've had this for three years now and I've had no issues so far, so I guess unless you are handling it roughly, I don't see why it could break.

The next best thing I can find is the Samsung USB 3.0 Flash Drive FIT 128GB (MUF-128BB) which takes size reduction to the extreme. (It's smaller than my Bluetooth mouse adapter which is almost invisible). It's 130mb/s read/write speed. Only problem is that it doesn't have the capability to be attached to a keyring. But I guess you can't have everything.

Comment: Thanks! But did you actually check the dimensions? It doesn't actually seem to be smaller than what I already have... yours is 57.40mm × 20.33mm × 10.96mm whereas mine is 53.34mm × 22.86mm × 10.16mm!

Comment: Sorry about that! I didn't notice that its larger. I'll have another look around and see if I can find a better option.

Comment: Are you sure that Samsung has that write speed? It seems to me that's the read speed and not the write speed...

Comment: @Mehrdad I looked on several sites and was able to test run it at a shop and it seems to me that it both reads and writes that fast